# Kal for iOS: there is a way to do not show the table view?

Tags: iphone, ios, kal

There is a way to do not show the UITableView in Kal, i.e., just the calendar (little squares) interface?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do this in code as Kal does not expose a way to do it natively. You'll have to edit the code in KalView.m.

Just comment out the below line in KalView.m addSubviewsToContentView: (line 179 in the GitHub repo I'm using).

```
[contentView addSubview:tableView];
```

This will result in a black box which fills the rest of the parent view. If you want a different color then you need to set a different color/background on the contentView or add your own `UIView` with the same frame as `tableview`. You could do something like this.

```
UIView *myView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:fullWidthAutomaticLayoutFrame;
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[contentView addSubview:myView];
```

This will replace the tableView with a plane `UIView` with a red background.